# how to keep ratio of the element's width and height when window size changes?

Tags: html, css

I have a IMG with style like this:

```
position: absolute;
left: 50px;
top: 30px;
width: 150px;
height: 120px;
```

So, this IMG will be displayed with ratio of width and height equal to 5/4.
How can I make the ratio still be 5/4 when the window size changes?